# Mongoose: search for users with certain regex query

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongoose

I have a mongoose query that searches for users that match a certain regex

```js
       let { q } = req.query;
        // prettier-ignore
        q = q.replace(".", '\.'); 

    
        // find user
        const users = await db.User.find({
            email: new RegExp(`${q}`, "ig"),
        });
```

I am trying to match the exact character  < . > DOT but for some reason, it doesn't work and the result is the regex < . > DOT "the any character notation".

which results in wrong logical results.

I want to match for the exact character < . > DOT   how to achieve this?

Example response for query "s.":

```js
[
    {
        "name": "hoo hoo",
        "email": "ahmeds.g.aafer@gmail.com",
        "img": "09b37a7b29eae24507192185957dc7c7"
    },
    {
        "name": "someuser",
        "email": "someuser@gmail.com",
        "img": "c226d980ff0d72d3799cb75c641fdd09"
    }
]
```

What I want the response to be:

```js
[
    {
        "name": "hoo hoo",
        "email": "ahmeds.g.aafer@gmail.com",
        "img": "09b37a7b29eae24507192185957dc7c7"
    },
    
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\\. instead of \. will make it work, \. says . is the spetial character when \ is the actual spetial one.

Comment: I tried this and same problem 

and fixed the question

Comment: Did you try replacing . for \\. instead?

Comment: \\. worked can you add this solution to your main answer so that I can accept it

Comment: and kindly do not use rude language like "what a head " in your next answers as it may lead to you getting banned

Comment: Ok, I will have it in mind in my next answers. I am new in the plattform and just getting started :)
Thanks